# How to upload file using NodeJs and Kafka?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, apache-kafka

I wanna upload a file from my client to server(nodeJs). server passes the file to Kafka server and the file should be uploaded in Kafka server.

Comment: Are you using Kafka for the proper use case? I don't think KAFKA is made for that.

Answer (score 1):

"File should be uploaded in Kafka server" doesn't really make sense. You can stream messages (bytes; Kafka doesn't care about format) from a client to a Kafka broker. Typically Kafka is not used for large messages - you'd stick the file on something like S3 and reference a pointer to it in your Kafka message instead.